# Setting channel url format to include value of entries fieldtype URL

Tags: url, entries-field

I have a channel with an entry type which has a simple dropdown for `{region}` and an entries fieldtype which links to a channel of destinations.

I'd like the URL format for the channel to be `/region/destination/slug`. If I do `/{region}/{destination.url}/{slug}` the output is `/region-name//entry-slug`, i.e. nothing is output for the destination.

What should I have where I currently have `{destination.url}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
{destination.first().slug}
```

Or if this is for Craft 3:

```
{destination.one().slug}
```